# Just started learning React a week ago, stuck on debugging why the input field unfocused after each key entry

Tags: reactjs

Below is just a simplified dummy example that reproduces this problem.

```
function MultiplierBox() {
  const [a, setA] = useState([1.0, 2.2])
  function updateA(index, newValue) {
    const newArray = [...a];
    newArray[index] = newValue;
    setA(newArray);
  }
  function Row({ a, index }) {
    function handleA(event) {
      const newValue = parseFloat(event.target.value)
      updateA(index, newValue)
    }
    return <input type="number" value={a[index]} onChange={handleA} />
  }
  return (<div className="MultiplierBox">
    {a}
    <Row a={a} index={0} />
    <Row a={a} index={1} />
  </div>);
}
```

What I tried:

- using a single value instead of arrays (works)
- checked the css style rules
- created a simplified version of the problem

What I expect:

- the input field stays focused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `Row` component *inside* of the `MultiplierBox` component. That means that every time MultiplierBox renders, a brand new Row function is created. It may have the same text as the old one, but as far as react can tell, it's a different type of component. So react unmounts the old row and mounts the new one. A newly-mounted input does not have focus.

The fix is to define all your components just once, at the top level. You will need to modify the Row component so that updateA is a prop that's passed down:

```
function Row({ a, index, onChange }) {
  function handleA(event) {
    const newValue = parseFloat(event.target.value);
    onChange(index, newValue);
  }
  return <input type="number" value={a[index]} onChange={handleA} />;
}

function MultiplierBox() {
  const [a, setA] = useState([1.0, 2.2]);
  function updateA(index, newValue) {
    const newArray = [...a];
    newArray[index] = newValue;
    setA(newArray);
  }

  return (
    <div className="MultiplierBox">
      {a}
      <Row a={a} index={0} onChange={updateA} />
      <Row a={a} index={1} onChange={updateA} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In general is it bad to define subcomponents within main components?

Comment: Yes, it is always a bad idea.